# Any MPXJ in Java example?

Tags: java, mpxj

I'm new to MPXJ would like to know more regarding MPXJ but I googled found lack of example or tutorial regarding it, any sample example regarding it? I will appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the ["getting started"](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/getting-started.html) pages on the web site for a general overview. There is also a small set of examples in the [sample package](http://mpxj.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mpxj/src/net/sf/mpxj/sample/) which forms part of the source distribution. This will give you an idea of the basics of handling project files.

If you have anything specific you'd like to see, either in the getting started documentation, or the sample code, I'm happy to add something for you.

Jon

p.s. I maintain MPXJ - hence my interest!

Comment: thanks Jon, by the way, which version of MPXJ should I use ? the latest or version 4.0?

Comment: Just found i set the percentage complete it does not show out, is that any way for me to set it? as all the output i tested in openproj. instead of Microsoft Project

Comment: No problem. I'd grab the latest from CVS, there are a lot of fixes. I'm planning to release a new version shortly. With regard to openproj, it's often a case of finding out which attributes it's expecting to see. Best way to do that is to create a sample file in openproj and save it as XML, then look at how it populates the attributes. You can use this to guide which attributes you need to set in MPXJ.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post has a nice simple example of writing a project file http://www.iniy.org/?p=337